# How to build a stable system for processing 90 millions of rows & transffering into live server every day?

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery, bigdata

I have an employee rewarding & tracking system for a company. The company I am developing a system for, providing me sales data with FTP every day. (They do not provide a webservice for this, unfortunately.) I have to store & process all the new sales and employee data and I have to calculate how many points employees won by selling, how many badges they have... (based on sales). I already have a system works correctly but I am thinking on moving these calculation processes to the cloud and just transfer the point data after calculations.  My system reads all the sales data and stores it in MySQL. Afterwards, a PHP script processes the raw data into point data. My webpages don't load raw data, they just need basic personal information and employee wallet balance.

In this case, which database system could be better for this? Which service(AWS, Gcloud etc..) suits for our needs? What could be done to make this system work faster?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What the heck are you tracking if you get 90M data points/day on sales?  My point is that you should "work smarter" not "work harder".  A point system should not require more than a couple minutes on your laptop, not some huge cloud installation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all make some processes parallel and async by introducing a message queue (download, file processing, calculations etc...). For PHP/MySQL the easiest recommendation is [Beanstalkd](http://kr.github.io/beanstalkd/) it has a nice [admin panel](https://github.com/kr/beanstalkd).

For larger steps you would  choose a cloud service like [Google BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/) where each month you have 1TB queries free, and costs for storage are low $10-20 for TB (Q1 2017). This requires that you insert a copy of your data into BigQuery either by streaming insert or by load jobs. Once the data is in, you can write SQL queries for longer periods even on large data sets. If you need to modify some rows by User Defined Functions, you can do that too inside BigQuery.

If you are looking for a MySQL replacement above 2000 QPS you can check out [Cloud Spanner](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/02/introducing-Cloud-Spanner-a-global-database-service-for-mission-critical-applications.html) here is a [Quizlet's great article what is Spanner good for](https://quizlet.com/blog/quizlet-cloud-spanner).